# How to install 7.x version of elastic search python client?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pip

I have installed elastic search using `pip3 install elasticsearch` seems like my application works only on elastic search version 7.x how can I install ES version 7.x. I have tried `pip3 install elasticsearch=7.0.1` but it's not working.
Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `==`:

```
pip3 install elasticsearch==7.0.1
```

Or limit version like this:

```
pip3 install "elasticsearch < 8"
```

(please note double quotes).